# How to define goal in RVIZ through python script

Tags: python, rviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am working on turtlebot 3 and i am trying to derive goal for robot through python script so user dont need to direct navigation goal over again n again. I tried to view move_base topic it only retrieves result once, for instance i want to direct navigation goal once and should look for msg itself based on script.

Any help ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283633/how-to-define-goal-in-rviz-through-python-script/) by [HassanM](https://answers.ros.org/users/33385/hassanm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can send navigation goals as follows:

```
from geometry_msgs.msg import Pose, Point, Quaternion

goal = MoveBaseGoal()
goal.target_pose.pose = Pose(Point(1.5, -4.85, 0), Quaternion(0.0, 0.0, 0.6, 0.77))
goal.target_pose.header.frame_id = "map" 
goal.target_pose.header.stamp = rospy.Time() 
self.sac.send_goal(goal, active_cb=self.active_callback, done_cb=self.done_callback, feedback_cb=self.feedback_callback)
```

You can define the callback functions, which you provide while sending the goal, as follows:

```
def done_callback(self):
     rospy.loginfo("done callback")
```

The rest is up to you.

---

Originally posted by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) with karma: 796 on 2018-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0